# Upload image to express server separately than the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, express

So I'm working with image upload from my React app where the backend is Node and Express. In my react component I have a form with input type file and submit button. I am trying to upload the image first ( to give the user an option to delete the uploaded image ) then submit the form with the name of the file that comes back from the image upload response. But right now I'm getting an empty object for `req.body` and undefined for `req.files` in my backend.

This is my React component with handlers:

```
const ImageUpload = () => {

    const handleImageUpload = ( e, idx ) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append( 'image', e.target.files[ 0 ] );
        dispatch( uploadImage( formData ) );
    }

    const handleFormSubmit= ( e ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
          <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} >
                 <input 
                        type="file" 
                        accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" 
                        onChange={( e ) => handleImageUpload( e, idx )}  
                 />

                 <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
          </form>
    )
}
```

This is how Redux action looks like:

```
export const uploadImage = ( imageData ) => async ( dispatch ) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post( '/api/campaigns/upload-image', imageData, config );

        dispatch({
            type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });
    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

This is how the backend looks like:

```
app.js

const express = require( 'express' );
const PORT    = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors    = require('cors');
const app     = express();

app.use( express.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) );
app.use( express.json() );
app.options( "*", cors( { origin: 'http://localhost:3000', optionsSuccessStatus: 200 } ) );
app.use( cors( { origin: "http://localhost:3000", optionsSuccessStatus: 200 } ) );



router.js 

const uploadImage = asyncHandler( async ( req, res ) => {
    console.log( 'req.body: ', req.body ); // {}
    console.log( 'req.files: ', req.files ); // undefined
} );
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it something like formData only works for form submissions?

Comment: where do you intend to store the file? on disk or cloud?

Comment: @sid Server's file system.

Answer (score 1):

**On Frontend:**

headers should be

```
headers: { 
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}
```

**On Backend:**

[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) is a classic way of handling file uploads in ExpressJS.

```
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' })
```

controller or your service:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('body data:', req.body);
    console.log('files data:', req.files);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: hey, was this helpful? please let me know!!

Comment: this helped me, multer really do the trick